# ios 6.0 setAttributedText crash

Tags: ios, ios6, nsattributedstring

```
- (IBAction)pinFieldChanged:(id)sender {
    UITextField *pinField = sender;
    float kerninig = 76.0;

    NSAttributedString *attributedString =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:pinField.text
        attributes:
        @{
            NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:36],
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:130.0/255.0 green:130.0/255.0 blue:130.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
            NSKernAttributeName : @(kerninig)
        }];
    if ([pinField respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
     [pinField setAttributedText:attributedString];
    }

}
```

My app is crashing under ios6.0 when i'm trying to set attributed text to text field, though this selector is available iOS 6.0 and later

Can you give me any idea why this could happen?

Thanks in advance!)

Comment: What is error message ?

Comment: error - exc_bad_access

Answer (score 0):

iOS5 may be expects a CTFont so use

```
 NSString* s = @"Yo ho ho and a bottle of rum!";
    NSMutableAttributedString* mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:s];
    __block CGFloat f = 18.0;
    CTFontRef basefont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Baskerville", f, NULL);
```

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS5bookExamples/ch23p689styledText1/p579p593styleText1/RootViewController.m

use below ios 6

```
 NSAttributedString *stringValue= [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"cocoalibrary.blogspot.com" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSAttributedString is not available below than IOS 6. See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000166-95039), you can found this line.

> In iOS 6 and later you can use attributed strings to display formatted
>   text in text views, text fields, and some other controls

Comment: sorry i've mistyped i'm using ios 6 and ios 7

Comment: @Roma Show your full error log and when get this error? in Which device? in which IOS?

Comment: read qusetion)
My app is crashing under ios6.0 when i'm trying to set attributed text to text field, though this selector is available iOS 6.0 and later

Comment: Hello what is this `My app is crashing under ios6.0`? what do you mean by `under ios 6.0`?

Comment: @Roma and mention where it is work with your device? It's working with  IOS7? or anyother?

Comment: @Roma Just comment this line `NSKernAttributeName : @(kerninig)` and check. I saw, it may not work with some font family.